# OrientDB - Returning JSON with embedded vertices from a match query

Tags: orientdb

I have issues returning a nice json with embedded vertices from the database.

Here is an example graph:

[image: graph in the studio]

Here is an example query:

`match {class: user, as: user, where: (name='tihomir')}
.both('hasA'){as: task}.both('hasA'){as: tag}
RETURN user, task.name, tag.name`

The result is the expected one:

[image]

But what I really need is something like this:

```
[
 {
  user: {
   name: "user_name",
   tasks: [{
    name: "task_name",
    tags: [{
     name: "tag_name"
    }]
   }]
  }
 }
]
```

I couldn't achieve this with the fetch API.

Comment: are you using v 2.2 or 3.0?

Comment: I'm using 3.0. rc2 I think it was. The latest one. I tried a lot of thing based on this issue and your comments there - https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/2118 But maybe this is not the right way to do it. I couldn't hit the right syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with "nested projections"?

The following should do the job:

```
match 
   {class: user, as: user, where: (name='tihomir')}
   .both('hasA'){as: task}.both('hasA'){as: tag}
RETURN user:{*, tasks:{*, tags:{*}}}
```

Full docs here:
https://orientdb.com/docs/3.0.x/sql/SQL-Projections.html#nested-projections

Comment: I'm getting an error:

`Error parsing query: match {class: user, as: user, where: (name='tihomir')} .both('hasA'){as: task}.both('hasA'){as: tag} RETURN user:{*, tasks:{*, tags:{*}}} ^ Encountered " ":" ": "" at line 1, column 120. Was expecting one of: <EOF> <LIMIT> ... <AS> ... ";" ... "," ... DB name="personal" DB name="personal"`

Answer (score 0):

@thinklinux you need version 3.0 or higher (not suitable for production) to do this the way Luigi Dell'Aquila does this.